# NetBeans IDE 8.2 auto layout mode can't turn off

Tags: codenameone

I would like to ask if anyone knows how to turn off auto layout mode off on NetBeans? I am new to it and just started learning how to build a mobile app. Couldn't find answer to it anywhere. I know I can delete this GUI builder, and when creating new one unselect auto layout mode, however, I do not want to create a new one.

[image: NetBeans GUI Builder screenshot]

Comment: That isn't the NetBeans GUI builder

Answer (score 0):

The core design of auto-layout assumes you will use only auto-layout mode so when you initially create a form you need to pick one mode or another and the assumption is that you won't replace it. I would advise against using the old mode as most use cases should be doable in auto-layout and it is superior.

If you want to try to hack something you can locate the `.gui` file matching your main file under the res directory hierarchy (you can see it in NetBeans by switching from the "Projects" view to the "Files" view. You can open the `.gui` file as an XML file and edit it e.g. this is an auto-layout GUI file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<component type="Form" layout="LayeredLayout" layeredLayoutPreferredWidthMM="0.0" 
   layeredLayoutPreferredHeightMM="0.0"  autolayout="true"
   title="GuiComponent" name="GuiComponent">
  <component type="Label" text="" icon="resFile:icon.png" name="Label">
    <layoutConstraint insets="0.0mm auto auto auto" referenceComponents="-1 -1 -1 -1" referencePositions="0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0" />
  </component>
  <component type="Label" text="Label" name="Label_1">
    <layoutConstraint insets="27.2mm auto auto 0.0mm" referenceComponents="-1 -1 -1 -1" referencePositions="0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0" />
  </component>
  <component type="TextField" text="TextField" name="Text_Field">
    <layoutConstraint insets="0.0mm 3.0mm auto 0.0mm" referenceComponents="0 -1 -1 1 " referencePositions="1.0 0.0 0.0 1.0" />
  </component>
</component>
```

You will notice that the top level `Form` has `autolayout`. Notice you will need to do the following:

- Set `autolayout` to `false`
- Set the layout manager to something else e.g. `BoxLayout`
- Add layout specific attributes

E.g. to change this to box layout I need to change the first entry to something like:

```
<component type="Form" layout="BoxLayout" boxLayoutAxis="Y"  autolayout="false"
   title="GuiComponent" name="GuiComponent">
```